# primeng tree does not show items

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an primeng tree that shows the data that it reads in just fine.[image]

the html has the following code snippet

```
     <!--style="width: 85%; height: 400px"-->
     <p-tree

             [value]="filesTree4"
             selectionMode="checkbox"
             [(selection)]="selectedFiles2">
     </p-tree>
```

Now I want to size the tree control. When I add the line above

```
         <p-tree
             style="width: 85%; height: 400px"
             [value]="filesTree4"
             selectionMode="checkbox"
             [(selection)]="selectedFiles2">
     </p-tree>
```

[image]

the commented one, now the image becomes

Anyone sees what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got two issues with the syntax you are using.

First, you have to bind to the style input for the primeng component, rather than trying to inline a style string.

Second, you pass a JSON object to the style input with your style properties.

So for example, this should work for you:

```
<p-tree
  [style]="{'width': '85%', 'height': '400px'}"
  [value]="filesTree4"
  selectionMode="checkbox"
  [(selection)]="selectedFiles2">
</p-tree>
```